# How to filter the Pandas serials

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

I got a data frame and the type of the elements of one serial is list. like:

Column [A, B] [A] [A,C] [A, B, C] etc.

I used the expression

```
df[[ item == [A] for item in df['Column'].tolist()]]
```

can only filter out the columns only contain A, but I want the [A, C] also be selected.
if I use the expression

```
df[[ item for item in df['Column'].tolist() if set(item).issuperset(set([A]))]]
```

will be get error

> 'int' object is not iterable

How can I filter the data frame by condition that A is included the Column. Thanks.

Comment: What is `A` in `set(A)`?

Comment: Sorry for wrong description of the question. I edited the question. A should be [A].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `apply` on Series to check if `A` in each value. Then use boolean indexing to filter dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column': [['A', 'B'], ['A'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]})

df_ = df[df['Column'].apply(lambda x: 'A' in x)]
```

```
print(df_)

      Column
0     [A, B]
1        [A]
2     [A, C]
3  [A, B, C]
```